# Regular expression to find the matching group and matching text enclosed between square brackets

Tags: regex

I have a string in which I am adding custom placeholders that are enclosed between **[[** and  **]]** brackets. I need a regular expression that extracts out the text between these brackets. One example is as follows:

Input:

```
[[[[ROOM_NO]]]] and [[ASSET_NAME]] and [[sfssfs]fs]]

Output:
Match 1:
Full match: ROOM_NO
Group: [[ROOM_NO]] 

Match 2:
Full match: ASSET_NAME
Group: [[ASSET_NAME]]
```

Third placeholder should not match as there is one square bracket between the two enclosing [[ ]]  brackets.

Comment: Should `[[[[ROOM_NO]]]]` be matched?

Comment: As I understand it, `\[\[\w+\]\]` should suffice

Comment: What have you tried? Please share the pattern that does not work for you, and let know what regex library you are using. In .NET and PCRE, solutions might differ considerably.

Comment: By what you've said in your question, [[[[ROOM_NO]]]] should've 3 matches: [[[[.ROOM_NO.]]]], [[[.[ROOM_NO].]]] and [[.[[ROOM_NO]].]] (delimited by .'s ), because all of those substrings are wrapped by [[ ]].

Comment: @IvánC.Yes. It should match as the text ROOM_NO is enclosed between [[ and ]]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\[\[([^\[\]]+)\]\]`.

[Try it Online!](https://regex101.com/r/Va3Llp/4)